# Neo4J + GraphAware framework logging & debugging

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

So I've been developing a GraphAware Runtime module to extend Neo4J functionality.
According to  GraphAware, in order to enable logging I need to add a slf4j provided dependency to my module and add an entry to custom-logback.xml file.

That unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Specifying custom log levels doesn't seem to affect what is being printed in the console, and adding a new appender (file) doesn't seem to take any effect, i.e. no files are created.

Did anyone have a go at adding logs to graphaware runtime modules?
Also, how would one debug such a module, if you have to deploy it to neo4j, and it's being run by the neo4j itself?

**UPDATE 1:**

So I'm using Neo4J 2.3.2 and the custom-logback.xml file didn't exist orignally in the package, and I had to create it.
I just checked and downloaded 2.2.8 version, and that file seems to exist in that package. Did anything change in the 2.3 version of Neo4J in terms of logging?

Comment: Hi, what version of neo4j are you developing on ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen I believe 2.3.2

Comment: We'll have a look at this asap and report back. May well be a change in Neo4j that we missed! Stay tuned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out adding a `logback.xml` file to your `conf` directory with contents along these lines seems to work perfectly. I'll update the docs, please let me know if that worked. Cheers!

```
<configuration>    
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %-5level %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.graphaware" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thanks a lot!
Any reason for that change? It breaks compatibility and for anybody upgrading from 2.2 this will not be obvious and potentially will cause a lot of headache :)

Comment: Not sure myself to be honest - I just found this quick fix without having time to dig deep into the causes. Will do though and report back. Glad it works!